# Monotouch and WCF, memory usage

Tags: .net, wcf, ipad, memory-management, xamarin.ios

I have WCF service hosted in web-site and Monotouch application which can display and update PDF documents from service. PDF files size can be from 1 byte to 20 Mb.
When I have few documents (less than 100, and total size of documents is 30Mb), the update process completes succesfully. But, when I have many documents (more than 300, and common size of documents is 100Mb), my program is terminating on iPad 1, but on iPad 2 is still working.

I think the problem in **memory usage**. iOS kills my app, when its uses many memory. But I don't know where the problem, maybe Monotouch GC don't clean memory from fileData byte arrays?

Method which update documents on iPad:

```
protected bool BeginUpdateProcess()
{
  try {
    var binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
    binding.MaxBufferSize = 52428800;
    binding.MaxBufferPoolSize = binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 52428800L;
    binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = 52428800;
    var endpoint = new EndpointAddress(string.Format("http://{0}/Services/UpdateDataService.svc", UpdateInfo.Instance.ServerIP));
    using (var dataService = new UpdateDataServiceClient(binding, endpoint)) {
        // Get document list for update
        int[] docIds;
        try {
            docIds = dataService.GetModifiedDocumentIds(mLastUpdated);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            LogWriter.Instance.WriteToLog("UpdateFromServiceEror: Can't load modified document ids list", ex);
            return false;
        }

        // Get each document content and save it to iPad
        for (int i = 0; i < docIds.Length; i++) {
            if (Canceled) {
                return true;
            }
            try {
                byte[] fileData = dataService.GetDocumentTransData(docIds[i]);
                SaveDocument(fileData);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                LogWriter.Instance.WriteToLog(string.Format("Can't load or save file, id={0}", docIds[i]), ex);
                return false;
            }
        }
        dataService.Close();
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    LogWriter.Instance.WriteToLog("Error when update from service", ex);
}
 }
```

Web-site WCF settings:

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
<behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Default">
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="Transport"
            closeTimeout="00:01:00"
            openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
            allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
            maxBufferSize="52428800" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="52428800"
            messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
            useDefaultWebProxy="true">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="64"
                        maxStringContentLength="52428800"
                        maxArrayLength="52428800"
                        maxBytesPerRead="16384"
                        maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
        </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<services>
    <service name="iDict.Site.Services.UpdateDataService" behaviorConfiguration="Default">
        <host>
            <baseAddresses>
                <add baseAddress="http://localhost:57709/Services/UpdateDataService.svc"/>
            </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Transport" contract="iDict.Site.Services.IUpdateDataService" />
    </service>
</services>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean by **common size** ? it looks like **total** size to me, e.g. does *When I have little documents (lower than 100, and common size of documents is 30Mb),* becomes "when I have **few** documents, **less** than 100, and the **total** size of documents is 30MB...

Comment: Yes, you are right. I corrected my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a few things that might help you:

- 52428800 is a big buffer for devices;
- Are the PDF documents transfered in XML ? If so you'll, at some point, have both your PDF document in a `string` (not very efficient, memory wise) and a `byte[] fileData`. That might go over the available RAM of the first generation iPad. A possible way to avoid this situation is having the web service that returns URLs to the files. Each URL can then be easily `Stream`'ed from a web server to a local file without using much memory;
- the iPad2 has more RAM the above might works on them but this would eventually fail for larger documents. Meanwhile using `Stream` would limit you to the storage space of the devices;
- Depending on the version of MonoTouch you're using you *might* be hitting [bug #386](http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=386). If you can I suggest you to try the latest MonoTouch release (beta at the moment) which solves those issues.